# Write String into a file, which the user chooses from <input type="file">

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to write a String to a file, which the user chooses from . I'm unable to do it because I need the fileName and fileLocation to write my String to the file. But the request.getParamater("") gives me just the fileName. I know that it won't return the fileLocation because of security issues. Then, how do I write my String from the file chosen on my jsp. Please advise.

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond No need to show any codes here. In fact that's a design question :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot write to that file directly.

*Short answer* : Make a copy file on server.

*Long answer*:

1) Get the file.

2) Save it on server.

3) Append to that file. Do not overwrite.

4) Again send back the file to user with `response`.

Comment: @PiyushMittal dynamic location ? What's that ? can you elaborate ?

Comment: @Suresh where do I get the file from ? Please ellaborate

Comment: where we will create the file? it is given by user or programmer will chose the location

Comment: dynamic location , means that he wants to choose where the file should be downloaded , but you cant do that , security reasons .

Comment: @Amrola The user must and must select the location.

Comment: @PiyushMittal We create the file on server. For ex: Tomcat server.

Comment: yes i understand , but i am telling you , that you cant do this , when the response of the servlet is written back to be downloaded as a file , it will be downloaded to the Downloads Folder in windows for example .

Comment: @Suresh I'm confused. When do I create the file ? I mean, your Step-1, how do I do that

Comment: @Amrola I don't want to download anything. I just need to write to the file, which the user selected through <input type="file">.

Comment: @inquisitive Then the answer will be `you can't`

Comment: step (4) of what @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ explained means in other words , "download" .

Comment: @Suresh Ok, at the end I can download the file, as you're saying. how do I get about it then.

Comment: @inquisitive Go for other question. Not in this.

Answer (score -2):

Do some steps

- Get file name using `getFileName()` method. Store it on server side
- if some one wants to Save Same file name again then you append Some Date after file Name. so you can easily get all the files without any code changes.
- After write `String` into file close the file and `flush` .
- See i have upload the file form Front End and Store it on Some local system . when you try to upload Same file again then it append Date with File name

  ```
  public class uploadFile {

  private File myFile;
  private String myFileContentType;
  private String myFileFileName;
  private String destPath;

   public String upload() throws IOException {
  try {

      destPath = System.getProperty("user.home") +    System.getProperty("file.separator") + "File-Uploads";
      File destFile = new File(destPath, myFileFileName);
      File file1 = new File(destFile.toString());
      boolean b = false;
      Date date = new Date();
      if (!(file1.exists())) {
          b = file1.createNewFile();

      }
      if (b) {
          FileUtils.copyFile(myFile, destFile);
      } else {
          String fileContent = "";
          File f = new File(file1.toString());
          FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream(f);
          byte[] bf = new byte[(int) f.length()];
          inp.read(bf);
          fileContent = new String(bf, "UTF-8");
          System.out.println("file===>" + fileContent);
          String filename = destFile.toString() + date;
          FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true);
          fw.write(fileContent);
          fw.close();
          FileUtils.copyFile(myFile, destFile);
         }

      return SUCCESS;
  } catch (IOException e) {
      return SUCCESS;
  }
  }

     public File getMyFile() {
       return myFile;
     }

   public void setMyFile(File myFile) {
   this.myFile = myFile;
    }

    public String getMyFileContentType() {
    return myFileContentType;
   }

  public void setMyFileContentType(String myFileContentType) {
  this.myFileContentType = myFileContentType;
   }

   public String getMyFileFileName() {
   return myFileFileName;
   }

   public void setMyFileFileName(String myFileFileName) {
   this.myFileFileName = myFileFileName;
    }
    }
  ```

Comment: So write String URL With String like String userHome=System.getProperty("user.home");